# Can't test simple Angular 12 guard with Karma

Tags: angular, typescript, karma-jasmine

I have tried several times, but it seems like I cannot create a unit test for a very basic Guard in Angular 12 which has

- canActivate
- canActivateChild

as its main methods.
Please find the following code:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class IsAuthenticatedGuard implements CanActivate, CanActivateChild {
  constructor(private authService: AuthService, private router: Router) {}

  canActivate(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
  ): Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<boolean | UrlTree> | boolean | UrlTree {
    return this.authService.getIsAuthenticated().pipe(
      tap(isAuth => {
        if (!isAuth) {
          // Redirect to login
          // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-floating-promises
          this.router.navigate(['/login']);
        }
      })
    );
  }

  canActivateChild(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
  ): Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<boolean | UrlTree> | boolean | UrlTree {
    return this.canActivate(route, state);
  }
}
```

**The `authService` call inside the `canActivate` method shall return an Observable obtained by a BehaviourSubject object using the `asObservable()` call.**
I have tried every possible test, but it seems like no comparison performed (`toBe`,`toEqual`, etc.) works for those two methods, nor is the spy on the navigation is triggered when the redirect is performed.

The following is a sample `spec.ts` class I created following some guides on the web:

```
function mockRouterState(url: string): RouterStateSnapshot {
  return {
    url
  } as RouterStateSnapshot;
}

describe('IsAuthenticatedGuard', () => {
  let guard: IsAuthenticatedGuard;
  let authServiceStub: AuthService;
  let routerSpy: jasmine.SpyObj<Router>;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [SharedModule, RouterTestingModule]
    });
    authServiceStub = new AuthService();
    routerSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj<Router>('Router', ['navigate']);
    guard = new IsAuthenticatedGuard(authServiceStub, routerSpy);
  });

  it('should be created', () => {
    expect(guard).toBeTruthy();
  });

  const dummyRoute = {} as ActivatedRouteSnapshot;
  const mockUrls = ['/', '/dtm', '/drt', '/reporting'];

  describe('when the user is logged in', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
      authServiceStub.setIsAuthenticated(true);
    });
    mockUrls.forEach(mockUrl => {
      describe('and navigates to a guarded route configuration', () => {
        it('grants route access', () => {
          const canActivate = guard.canActivate(dummyRoute, mockRouterState(mockUrl));
          expect(canActivate).toEqual(of(true));
        });
        it('grants child route access', () => {
          const canActivateChild = guard.canActivateChild(dummyRoute, mockRouterState(mockUrl));
          expect(canActivateChild).toEqual(of(true));
        });
      });
    });
  });

  describe('when the user is logged out', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
      authServiceStub.setIsAuthenticated(false);
    });
    mockUrls.forEach(mockUrl => {
      describe('and navigates to a guarded route configuration', () => {
        it('does not grant route access', () => {
          const canActivate = guard.canActivate(dummyRoute, mockRouterState(mockUrl));
          expect(canActivate).toEqual(of(false));
        });
        it('does not grant child route access', () => {
          const canActivateChild = guard.canActivateChild(dummyRoute, mockRouterState(mockUrl));
          expect(canActivateChild).toEqual(of(false));
        });
        it('navigates to the login page', () => {
          // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/unbound-method
          expect(routerSpy.navigate).toHaveBeenCalledWith(['/login'], jasmine.any(Object));
        });
      });
    });
  });
});
```

When I run the test file, I get something like this:

> Expected object to have properties
> _subscribe: Function
> Expected object not to have properties
> source: Observable({ _isScalar: false, source: BehaviorSubject({ _isScalar: false, observers: [  ], closed: false, isStopped: false, hasError: false, thrownE
> rror: null, _value: false }) })
> operator: MapOperator({ project: Function, thisArg: undefined })
> Error: Expected object to have properties
> _subscribe: Function ...

Apparently, Karma expects a ScalarObservable of some sort, plus the navigation towards `['/login']` is not detected.

Would you mind giving me some advice on how to perform this test?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can provide all the services in the `providers`-array of the 

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [SharedModule, RouterTestingModule],
     providers: [...]
    });
```

Then you can take the guard out of the TestBed and use `waitForAsync` to let angular wait for all async operations to finish in this test.

Comment: Also your consts `canActivate` and `canActivateChild ` are Observables, so you can't use them in `expect`. Instead, you should subscribe to them and test the result there. `guard.canActivate(dummyRoute, mockRouterState(mockUrl)).subscribe((result) => expect(result).toBeTrue())`

Comment: @FabianGosebrink would you mind giving me a sample of your answer directly in my code?

Comment: @vitaliykotov whenever I try typing the `subscribe` clause there, IntelliJ complains about it stating that it cannot be called there.

Comment: that's because of return type you've set for `canActivate` and `canActivateChild`. If  your `AuthService.getIsAuthenticated` returns `Observable<boolean>`, then these methods should also have such type as they just return a call for auth service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I would configure TestBed module and test guard:

```
describe('IsAuthenticatedGuard', () => {
  const mockRouter = {
    navigate: jasmine.createSpy('navigate'),
  };
  const authService = jasmine.createSpyObj('AuthService', ['getIsAuthenticated']);
  let guard: IsAuthenticatedGuard;

  beforeEach(
    waitForAsync(() => {
      TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        providers: [
          IsAuthenticatedGuard,
          { provide: Router, useValue: mockRouter },
          { provide: AuthService, useValue: authService },
        ],
      }).compileComponents();
    }),
  );

  beforeEach(() => {
    guard = TestBed.inject(IsAuthenticatedGuard);
  });

  describe('when the user is logged in', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
      authService.setIsAuthenticated.and.returnValue(of(true));
    });

    it('grants route access', () => {
      guard.canActivate({} as ActivatedRouteSnapshot, {} as RouterStateSnapshot).subscribe((result) => {
        expect(result).toBeTrue();
      });
    });

    it('grants child route access', () => {
      guard.canActivateChild({} as ActivatedRouteSnapshot, {} as RouterStateSnapshot).subscribe((result) => {
        expect(result).toBeTrue();
      });
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, @vitaliy.

I adjusted some things in both the guard itself and the test file, and managed to get it through.

Here is the final test file:

```
describe('IsAuthenticatedGuard', () => {
  const mockRouter = {
    navigate: jasmine.createSpy('navigate')
  };
  const authService = jasmine.createSpyObj<AuthService>('AuthService', ['getIsAuthenticated']);
  let guard: IsAuthenticatedGuard;

  beforeEach(
    waitForAsync(() => {
      void TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        providers: [
          IsAuthenticatedGuard,
          {
            provide: Router,
            useValue: mockRouter
          },
          {
            provide: AuthService,
            useValue: authService
          }
        ]
      }).compileComponents();
    })
  );

  beforeEach(() => {
    guard = TestBed.inject(IsAuthenticatedGuard);
  });

  describe('when the user is logged in', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
      authService.getIsAuthenticated.and.returnValue(of(true));
    });

    it('grants route access', () => {
      void guard.canActivate({} as ActivatedRouteSnapshot, {} as RouterStateSnapshot).subscribe(result => {
        expect(result).toBeTrue();
      });
    });

    it('grants child route access', () => {
      guard.canActivateChild({} as ActivatedRouteSnapshot, {} as RouterStateSnapshot).subscribe(result => {
        expect(result).toBeTrue();
      });
    });
  });

  describe('when the user is logged out', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
      authService.getIsAuthenticated.and.returnValue(of(false));
    });

    it('does not grant route access', () => {
      void guard.canActivate({} as ActivatedRouteSnapshot, {} as RouterStateSnapshot).subscribe(result => {
        expect(result).toBeFalse();
        expect(mockRouter.navigate).toHaveBeenCalledWith(['/login']);
      });
    });

    it('does not grant child route access', () => {
      guard.canActivateChild({} as ActivatedRouteSnapshot, {} as RouterStateSnapshot).subscribe(result => {
        expect(result).toBeFalse();
        expect(mockRouter.navigate).toHaveBeenCalledWith(['/login']);
      });
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need the `mockRouter` as you can add the `RouterTestingModule` in the `imports` array and do a

```
  const router: Router;

  beforeEach(
    waitForAsync(() => {
      void TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        imports: [RouterTestingModule], //ADD THIS HERE
        providers: [
          IsAuthenticatedGuard,
          {
            provide: AuthService,
            useValue: authService
          }
        ]
      }).compileComponents();
    })
  );

  beforeEach(() => {
    guard = TestBed.inject(IsAuthenticatedGuard);
    router = TestBed.inject(Router); //ADD THIS HERE
  });
```

As you are subscribing in a test you need to add the `waitForAsync()` because the Test should wait until every observable has been executed and finished.

For example

```
it('does not grant child route access', waitForAsync(() => {
      guard.canActivateChild({} as ActivatedRouteSnapshot, {} as RouterStateSnapshot).subscribe(result => {
        expect(result).toBeFalse();
        expect(mockRouter.navigate).toHaveBeenCalledWith(['/login']);
      });
    }));
```

Otherwise it may be that the test has been finished before the subscribe has been called, and you `expect` nothing.